# How do go about deep linking into my PhoneGap App using Pushwoosh's API for push notifications?

Tags: cordova, build, push-notification

Pushwoosh has documentation for native integration but nothing that I can find for PhoneGap Build based apps. I'd like to send a push notification using their API and have it deep link into a specific section of my app. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on my first integration right now.  This is a good place to start for documentation on integrating Pushwoosh into a PhoneGap app:

http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/cordova-phonegap